# This operator is it compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

Let  $\Omega \subset \ R$ be bounded  and regular domain and
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
\nabla  :& H^1(\Omega) & \longrightarrow &L^2(\Omega)\\
& y & \longmapsto   &  \displaystyle \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}
\end{array}
Is the following operator compact

\begin{array}{ccccc}
K  :& H^1(\Omega) & \longrightarrow & L^2(\Omega)\\
& y & \longmapsto   &  \displaystyle\int_0^x\nabla y(s)ds
\end{array}

Comment: For $n\ge 2$ the integral $\int_0^x$ does not much sense. $x$ is a vector. Also you are using $x$ for $\int_0^x$ and for $y(x)\,dx$ which is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have edited my question and now what about the case when n=1?

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ a function in $H^1(\Omega)$ is absolutely continuous, so you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to get that
$$\int_0^xy'(s)\,ds=y(x)-y(0).$$
If you have a bounded sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ then by the Ascoli-Arzela theorem a subsequence $\{y_{n_j}\}_{j}$ will converge uniformly. So yes, the operator $K$ is compact since by uniform convergence $y_{n_j}(x)-y(0)\to y(x)-y(0)$.